# IOS web app always launches with splash screen

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

I have a web page that loads as an IOS web app and also loads a splash screen when first loading.
But now it seems to show the splash screen even when the the web app is running in the background of and ios device. I need to enable multitasking so my web app will only show the splash screen at its first launch.

How do i got about doing this?

Comment: The way that mechanism works is really mysterious to me.

Comment: This is an interesting question imo - there must be a way around it as not *every* app has a splash screen.

Comment: It seems that there are people on here who want it to display everytime the app is loaded, even when it is in the background. I just want it to run like a normal app would

Comment: Just a possibility - have you tried screenshotting the *blank UI* of your application and setting that as the 'splash screen'? When I open an app on my iPhone that *doesn't* have a splash screen, and it takes a little while to load, it's just a picture of their app background and UI. You could try this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web app will always restart everytime you open it. To enable multitasking you can persist the state of the app in the LocalStorage and restore the state upon restart.

For more info see similar questions:
[Stop native web app from reloading itself upon opening on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454083/1340601)
[Stop reloading of web app launched from iPhone Home Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943685/1340601)

There is also an article in Safari Developer Library:
[Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1-SW1)