# Blank screenshot in app switcher in iOS 7 (HTML web app)

Tags: ios7, screenshot, iphone-web-app

When switching between a Home Screen HTML web app to another app and back (iOS 7), the web app screenshot is just of a blank page.  Is there a way of ensuring the screenshot reflects the actual state of the app before it went into background mode?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the web app screenshot'?  Do you mean the webpage is blank, or are you trying to create a screenshot using some other app?

Comment: I'm referring to the screenshot that iOS takes of your app under this situation: 1. Open a web app (app A); 2. Double click home button and switch to another app. 3. Double click the home button again to switch back to app A. The screenshot that is displayed of app A is a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because your app gets reloaded everytime. You might want to look at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291784/stop-native-web-app-from-reloading-itself-upon-opening-on-ios) or [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930771/stop-reloading-of-web-app-launched-from-iphone-home-screen)

It looks like it is default behaviour and the only way you can work around this is to use localStorage.

EDIT: Of course you would have to save the state of your app everytime the user makes an interaction since you do not have AppDelegate methods which get triggered when your app goes to background.