# Mobile Web App on iOS reloads to start page every time Home button is pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, html

So i have mobile web application marked with 
**apple-mobile-web-app-capable** meta tag so it loads and navigates in frame less browser view and can be pinned to iOS home screen.
Now this issue i have is, every time i press Home button to switch to another app or just switch off and come back, application imminently goes to the first page.
In my case its a login page, not sure how to stop it, cant find an answer, this behavior looks really stupid and useless, as i cant have users logging in every time the second they switched off to another app.

Comment: I know this is almost a year old question, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291784/stop-native-web-app-from-reloading-itself-upon-opening-on-ios#