# iPhone web-app from home screen always reloads switching between apps

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, multitasking, homescreen

I'm working on a mobile web app (website) that requires you to add it to the home screen. When you open it, and switch to another app, then go back to my web app, the whole app reloads. It shows the splash screen and doesn't even remember where you last were.

Is there a way around this? I can't find any details in the iOS docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930771/stop-reloading-of-web-app-launched-from-iphone-home-screen) will answer your question.

You can't avoid this refresh behavior. You should work with the HTML5 local storage to persist  the state of your application and use it when the application is launched to restore his state.

Here is a link to the [Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1-SW1) focussing on your question.