# pageshow/pagehide events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I came across `pageshow`/`pagehide` events, but I'm not really sure how they work.

I registered them on `document`, and later on `window` object, but they never fired.

I expected them to fire after the page is loaded for `pageshow`, and when I go to some other page for `pagehide`, but this never happened.

Where can I find more information about these events?

Comment: I think they are jQuery Mobile events. Hope you are using those with jQuery Mobile ?

Comment: Try `.onload` and `.onunload`

Comment: No, I don't use jQuery Mobile. pageshow is part of the standard, but I'm not sure about pagehide, I am not able to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was quite vague but I think that you can learn a little 
using this post 
http://aawaara.com/post/74543339755/smallest-piece-of-code-thats-going-to-change-the

They use them like this, but it seems as the way you are using them

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(evt){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, false);
```