# When you add a webapp to the homescreen in iOS you can no longer store cookies

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, mobile-safari

So my goal is to use offline storage to do this.

The main goal is remembering login information.

In what form should I store the data and how should I actually go about doing this?

Examples would be great, thanks!

Comment: why do you think you can't use cookies? is that an iOS5 change?

Comment: I guess because they stop working, for others too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813599/iphone-bookmark-to-homescreen-removes-cookies-and-session

Comment: hmm. I can't replicate it, but thanks for the heads up...I second looking into cache.manifest as an alternate

Answer (score 2):

Use persistent storage. See [this example from Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

UPD: Apple recommends using persistent storage facilities of HTML5 now. However, the above mentioned article is quite informative.

Comment: Link is out of date. You should copy the relevant details into the answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

think about the manifest system and store a dynamic javascript file with login variable inside... just an idea