# How to detect a mobile website visitor has previously saved my page to their homepage

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

This previous question addressed extending a php session across multiple visits by using a sessionid-in-a-persistent-cookie approach:

[iPhone "Bookmark to Homescreen" removes cookies and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813599/iphone-bookmark-to-homescreen-removes-cookies-and-session)

It seems that this might solve my problem, assuming that the sessionid and cookie can be set only on saving the site to homepage AND can be detected on return visit.

If detected, i could serve a prompt to the user that the site is already on their homepage .. and would provide them the best experience.

If the cookie is not detected, they would be prompted to save to homepage.

1) Can the session id be set only if the user saves to their homepage .. even if that is thru some routine run from the webpage which invokes the "save to webpage" .. if THAT's even possible?

2) can someone point me to resources for setting the session id and for detecting the cookie on visitor's return?

And can this be done on Android, etc?

Thanks. Pretty clueless here but trying to find a solution..

Any other ideas welcomed...

Comment: You could store it in localStorage?

Comment: I think the persistent cookie idea is fine .. or,sure, localstorage .. but the main question is how to detect the "save to homepage" event OR the "already present on homepage" condition.