# Share session between safari and standalone mode (Add to Home Screen)

Tags: javascript, ios, session, cookies, safari

Is there any way to share session between safari and browser standalone mode? 
The solution in the following post doesn't work on iOS 9.
[iPhone "Bookmark to Homescreen" removes cookies and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813599/iphone-bookmark-to-homescreen-removes-cookies-and-session)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like latest iOS update, 17.2??,  copies session when adding to home screen. Once created the sessions are no longer synched, so logging out on Home Screen app will not log you out in safari app.