# Keep a django app user logged in with safari "add to home screen"

Tags: django, mobile-safari

I have added my django app to my iphone home screen with the safari bookmark. As it has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813599/iphone-bookmark-to-homescreen-removes-cookies-and-session), when the app is opened trough this bookmark, the user is every time logged out.

I wonder how can I keep my user logged in to my django app.
Is there a way to manage this with Django?

Comment: The link you give has the answer. Can you tell us what your specific problem is with implementing that answer?

Comment: I wonder if there is django-specific solution for this.